# Change the color of the text that appears at the beginning of startup

Tags: 13.04, xfce, etc

I would like to know how to make the "OK" in "[ OK ]" green, like there is displayed at the startup of OpenSuse:

> Starting xxxxxxxxxx  [ OK ] <- Green Color
>   Starting xxxxxxxxxx  [ OK ] <- Green Color
>   Starting xxxxxxxxxx  [ OK ] <- Green Color
>   Starting xxxxxxxxxx  [ OK ] <- Green Color
>   Starting xxxxxxxxxx  [ OK ] <- Green Color
>   Starting xxxxxxxxxx  [ OK ] <- Green Color

At the beginning of startup in Ubuntu the [ OK ] is white and not GREEN.
Does anyone have any ideas? I have tried modifying `/lib/lsb/init-functions` and `/etc/lsb-base-logging.sh`, and it doesn't work after I made some changes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's standard ANSI, you could use the following as a guide : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

You'll see all the cursor control information and the colour sequences.

If it's not ANSI, I'm stumped.

Comment: that's not the solution, apparently it will be in /etc/lsb-base-logging.sh & /lib/lsb/init-functions. After consulting some ideas on different forums nothing works. :( Like there is on OPENSUSE at The begining " Starting Services xxxxxxx [ OK ] " [ ok ] is in GREEN COlour.